# How can I solve this riddle using for loops in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

The question asks

Holy  digits  Batman!   The  Riddler  is  planning  his  next  caper  somewhere  on Pennsylvania Avenue.  In his usual sporting fashion, he has left the address in the form of a puzzle.  The address on Pennsylvania is a four-digit number with the following properties:

- All four digits are different
- The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place
- The number is odd
- The sum of the digits is 27.

Write a function that uses a loop or loops that returns the address where the Riddler plans to strike.

so I know I have to use devision and then modulus operators to pop the numbers. but I cant get anything to print, so I went back to fix my code but got stuck

```
def Riddler():
    #all numbers have to be odd
    # all numbers when added up have to equal 27
    address = 0 #has to basically equal print(ones, tens, hundred, thousands)
    thousands = 0 # thousands = tens * 3
    hundreds = 0
    tens = 0
    ones =  0

    for i in range(1000,10000):
        #print(address)
        one = int(i%10)
        ten = int(i//10)%10
        hundreds = int(i//100)%10
        thousands = int(i//1000)%10
        if (thousands!= hundreds) and (thousands!= tens) and (thousands!= ones) and (hundreds!= tens) and (hundreds!= ones) and (tens !=ones):
            if thousands == (ten*3):
                print(thousands) #was just trying to see what this would print

Riddler()
```

If someone could write this in a better more clean way using for loops It would greatly help me see how i could improve my code. I did not start learning while loops to the fullest yet, but i'm also curious how this would look like in a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the fastest way, but it gets the result:

```
def riddler():
    for n in range(9031,10000,2):
        d = [int(c) for c in str(n)]
        if sum(d) == 27:
            if d[0]==(d[2]*3):
                if not any(True if d[i] in d[i+1:] else False for i in range(len(d))):
                    return n

riddler()
```

**side note**

I understand the goal of the exercise is to use `for` loops, but, you should note that brute force is useless as a bit of reasoning is enough to get the result.

Note that from condition 2 there are only three possible combinations of potential thousands/tens digits: `(3,1), (6,2), (9,3)`.

However only the sum in pair `(9,3)` is "large" enough (`12`) to get `25` with the other two digits. So you instantaneously get `9` for the thousands and `3` for the tens. What about the other two digits? Well, the sum has to be `25`, so there are four potential pairs: `(6,9), (9,6), (7,8), (8,7)`.

Clearly `(6,9)` and `(9,6)` violate condition 1, `(7,8)` violates condition 3, so the only good pair for hundreds and ones digits is `(8,7)`.

And you get the solution: `9837`.

Comment: Thanks. With a bunch of trial and error and then finally understanding it fully I came up with a solution that gives me 9837.

Answer (score 0):

Why loops? Use list comprehensions:

```
# The sum of the digits is 27. 
# The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place = 3000+
# The number is odd  => 3001+, only odd numbers
# using strings of numbers for next 2 steps
sum27 = [ str(n) for n in range(3001,10000,2) if sum(map(int,str(n)))==27]
print(sum27)

# All four digits are different 
digit_diff = [ n for n in sum27 if len(set(n))==4]
print(digit_diff)


# The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place 
solution = [int(n) for n in digit_diff if int(n[0])==3*int(n[2])]
print(solution) # [9837]
```

Or shorter:

```
riddle = [n for n in range(3001,10000,2) 
         if sum(map(int,str(n)))==27 
         and len(set(str(n)))==4
         and int(str(n)[0])==3*int(str(n)[2])]
```

---

With some logic you can reduce your probing:

- if `thou` is 3 times the `ten` value, `thou` can only be a multiplicaple of 3: `3,6,9`
- `ten` is always `thou // 3`
- `hun` can not be `thou` or `ten`
- `one` must be odd and can not be `thou`,`hun` or `ten`

---

```
for thou in {3,6,9}:  
    ten = thou//3 
    for hun in range(10):
        if hun in (thou,ten): 
            continue
        for one in range(1,10,2): # odd values only
            if one in (thou,hun,ten): 
                continue
            elif one+ten+hun+thou == 27:  # sum27
                print(thou, hun, ten, one, sep="")
```

Output:

```
9837
```

Comment: This is a practice problem and im only allowed to use loops as I have not yet learned sets